# wp post title in foundation tooltip

Tags: wordpress, tooltip, zurb-foundation

I would like to show the next/prev post link title in a tooltip, i tried several options, but it won't display it. The place is "SHOW POST TITLE HERE".
the code:

```
<?php next_post_link('%link', '<span data-tooltip aria-haspopup="true" class="has-tip tip-bottom" title="SHOW POST TITLE HERE"><i class="fa fa-angle-left fa-2x"></i></span>
'); ?>
```

thnx in advance

Answer (score 0):

To show title use `%title` , See [**Documentation**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_post_link)

```
<?php next_post_link( '%link', '<span data-tooltip aria-haspopup="true" class="has-tip tip-bottom" title="%title"><i class="fa fa-angle-left fa-2x"></i></span>' ); ?>
```